# Error C1083: Cannot open source file: "stdafx.cpp': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have the above error and have followed all solutions but does not fix.

This is my stdafx.h file. I have it in the target directory, I can see the file and the full path goes to there. In addition, I have created a win32 project. Why is my code not working?

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>



// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
```

ACTUAL CODE:

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application. //
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;   return 0; }
```

Comment: ***Cannot open source file: "stdafx.cpp': No such file or directory*** Create `stdafx.cpp`. Or just disable precompiled headers. And remove stdafx.cpp from your project.

Comment: Now it tells me it cannot find "consoleapplication1.cpp" that is the name of the code that I wrote with helloworld. So it is struggling to find the source files.

Yet it is in the full path location that is specified so it is not missing.

Comment: It seems you messed up your project somehow. Maybe it would be easier to start over with a new Win32 console project.

Comment: So I had a look if I could delete the source files and then re add them. When I try to search for them, Visual studio doesn't recognise them and show them as files.

I have tried making the project anew previously and it did not work. I am selecting Win32 Console Application when starting it, under visual c++

Comment: You have something very wrong with your system. Maybe you have a virus or serious install issue with Visual Studio. And in either case perhaps it will be better to ask about this on the microsoft forums.

Comment: I restarted visual studio and I then right clicked on source file and clicked compile. After clicking on that and then compiling on the main it worked fine.

When I then tried adding a function and compiling it returned to the old error.

Comment: Update:

I compile when I create the project without having any main code down. Then I write the code, compile again and things work fine.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. Absolutely not the expected behavior. I have no good guesses why your compiler / system is misbehaving this way.

Answer (score 7):

For the record, I had this problem when cloned a repo using git from the Ubuntu shell in Windows 10.

After I cloned the repo to a different location usin git from a Windows shell, the problem went away and the solution builds fine.

The issue was that the build scripts were looking for 'stdafx.cpp' in a folder with uppercase name (`C:\GIT\LIBRARYX\SRC\`) and this path did not work if the solution was cloned using git from Ubuntu bash.